# how to handle a list of checkbox?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, checkbox, checkboxlist

I am developing a page which display data from service on the View and allow users to filter it.
There is a column for Countries, which allow users to filter.

I am not able to figure out a way to create a list of checkbox so that I can grab all selected values in one param like string[] countries (in the action method).

Can't use classic way :

```
<input type="checkbox" name="countries" value="USA" />USA<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="countries" value="Canada" />Canada<br />
```

This does pass the values in URL but doesn't set them back on post back (keeping checked onpostback).

I tried using checkboxlist (http://goo.gl/TUvZzu) but seemed to complicated for my Modal.

Since mine is a very straight forward Model :

```
public string Title { get; set; }
public string Website { get; set; }
public string Address1 { get; set; }
public string Address2 { get; set; }
public string City { get; set; }
public string Zip { get; set; }
public string State { get; set; }
public string Country { get; set; }
```

I appreciate your time and help.

Comment: do you want to use jquery????

Comment: @Kartikeya: I can until it solves the purpose but I need to send these values to Action Method and set them back (keep the state maintained).

Comment: Is there a reason you're sold on using a check box list? Why can't you just hardcode the checkboxes and build your `string[]` in the controller?

Comment: @MatthewHaugen : The Country list changes on each filtering, I can still write them via iterating the Modal but how would I have the values as string[] to the controller, and razor handling to set the  value properly on postback. ?

Comment: Create a view model that represents what you want to display and post back

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to include a collection of countries within your view model to hold the selected values and allow them to be sent in the post.

I would also create a Country object to hold the Id, Name and Selected values.

In order for the model to be posted back you need to index each item in the view, this allows the model binder to pick it up.

**Models**

```
public class AModel
{
    public AModel()
    {
        Countries = new List<Country>();    
    }

    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Website { get; set; }
    public string Address1 { get; set; }
    public string Address2 { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string Zip { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
    // Country collection
    public List<Country> Countries { get; set; }

}

    public class Country
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }                
        public bool Checked { get; set; }           
    }
```

**View for loop**

```
@for(var i = 0; i < Model.Countries.Count; i++)
{

    <dt>
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => Model.Countries[i].ID)
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => Model.Countries[i].Name)
        @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => Model.Countries[i].Checked)
    </dt>
    <dd>
        @Model[i].Name
    </dd>

}
```

Note the for loop instead of foreach to enable model binding and the hidden fields to allow the values to be posted back to the controller

http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx/

**Controller post**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(AModel model)
{
    //All the selected countries are available in the model

    return View(model);
}
```

[**Working example**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Z6YoVQ)

Comment: Thanks a lot for elaborate answer, I am trying to understand how I can fit it in my Modal, sorry about the Animal names it actually meant countries but I copied the code example from somewhere, I have updated the post.

Comment: If you don't mind please update the answer values also accordingly, for better understanding, Thanks a lot once agian.

Comment: @VishalSachdeva Hi I have updated the code with a description and changed it to Country for you.

Comment: No problem. Good luck with the rest. @VishalSachdeva

Comment: Hi there again, I should have mentioned I need values in QS so that people can share the filtered results.and the route values are mapped as argument on Action method in order to filter the model. This example wont solves that purpose right :( ?

Comment: @vishal-sachdeva Hi, I would create another question & specify those needs. Someone will answer it I'm sure. I am outside without PC.

Comment: No probs, will try & take a look tomorrow if it's not answered already. @vishal-sachdeva